# A question about decision tree complexity

Tags: untagged

Let $f$ be a Boolean function. Is it possible that for some $x$ it holds that $DT(f|_{x=0}) = DT(f)$, but $DT(f|_{x=1}) < DT(f)$?

Here $DT(f)$ is decision tree complexity, i.e. the minimum depth of a decision tree that computes $f$.

Comment: By DT do you mean decision tree depth, or size? Do you mean for all x or there is an x?

Comment: @RyanWilliams Depth, there is an $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Let $g(y)$ be an arbitrary non-constant boolean function ($y$ can be an arbitrarily long vector of boolean variables), and let
$$f(x,a_0,a_1,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 &\textrm{if $x=0$, and $a_0=a_1$,} \\
a_{g(y)}&\textrm{if $x=1$, or $a_0\neq a_1$.}
\end{array}\right.$$
We have:

- $DT(f)\leq DT(g)+2$, by first querying $a_0$ and $a_1$. If they are equal then query $x$, otherwise compute $g(y)$.
- $DT(f|_{x=1})\leq DT(g)+1$. by first compute $g(y)$, then query $a_{g(y)}$.
- $DT(f|_{x=0})\geq DT(g)+2$. Take the optimal decision tree $T$ of $f|_{x=0}$ which computes
  $$f_{x=0}(a_0,a_1,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  0 &\textrm{if $a_0=a_1$,} \\
  a_{g(y)}&\textrm{if $a_0\neq a_1$.}
  \end{array}\right.$$
  Every path in $T$ has to query at least one of $a_0$ or $a_1$. Without loss of generality consider a path where $a_0$ is first queried, we only look at the branch that $a_0=1$. In this branch the function is
  $$f_{x=0,a_0=1}(a_1,y)=\neg g(y)\wedge\neg a_1.$$
  Setting $a_1=0$, each path in the branch decides the value of $g(y)$, and $a_1$ must also be queried either on the path or at the leaf where $g(y)=0$. This means that, by doing so for every path, we get a decision tree for $g$ where each path of length $\ell$ corresponds to a path of length $\ell+2$ in $T$.

Therefore we get $DT(f)=DT(f|_{x=0})=DT(g)+2> DT(f|_{x=1})$.

Comment: I don’t think that “every path in the decision tree has to query both $a_0$ and $a_1$” is true. If you start by computing $g(y)$ and $a_{g(y)}$, then if the latter is $0$, you know the answer is $0$ without querying $a_{1-g(y)}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think that Wei Zhan is right. Let $g(y)=y$. Then $f_{x=0, y=0} = a_0 \not \to a_1$;  $f_{x=0, a_0=0} = a_1 \land y$; $f_{x=0, a_1=0} = a_0 \not \to y$.

Comment: Thank you! Just an observation: $DT(g) =1$ because $g(y)=y$ or $g(y)= \neg y$ :)

Comment: @AlexeyMilovanov Yes, for the special case $g(y)=y$ one can check that $DT(f\restriction_{x=0})=3$ by hand. But the argument as stated is not correct for arbitrary $g$. Since the answer says that $g$ is “an arbitrary non-constant boolean function”, I assume the intention is that $y$ is a vector of variables.

Comment: Again: why “every path in the branch must also query $a_1$”? Consider the dual of my first comment: first compute $g(y)$, and query $a_{1-g(y)}$. If the latter is $1$, the answer is $0$ without needing to query $a_{g(y)}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Right, I also realized it soon after I made the first edit. Now it should be correct (finally!).

Comment: I’m sorry, but I still can’t make sense of the argument. So you look at a node where $a_0$ is first queried, and consider the $a_0=1$ branch. Fine. Now, every path in this branch that’s consistent with the setting $a_1=0$ decides $g(y)$, yes. But it’s perfectly possible that some of these paths decide that $g(y)=1$ and terminate without querying $a_1$. So how can you conclude that *every* path of length $\ell$ corresponds to a path of length $\ell+2$ in $T$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If it decides that $g(y)=1$, and the tree is optimal so no redundant query, then the last query also has an outcome that $g(y)=0$. If $a_1$ was not queried on the path, $a_1$ must be queried at this leaf.

Comment: Oh, I see, now I get it. (There's a borderline case when the last query before the leaf is the one that queried $a_0$, but in this case it also works out.) Thank you for the explanation.